# iphone:UItableviewcell duplicates when using table reload

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uitableview, reload

My tableview gets duplicated when I use `[tableview reloadData]`.I used this to refresh the tableview when I move back.How could I overcome the issue?

This is my code.

```
#define kMyTag 1
#define despTag 2
#define subTag 3

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    [self.tableview reloadData];
}    
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    AsyncImageView *asyncImageView = nil;
    UILabel *label = nil;
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:nil];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:nil] ;

        UILabel *mainLabel=[[UILabel alloc]init];
        mainLabel.tag = kMyTag; // define kMyTag in your header file using #define
        mainLabel.frame=CGRectMake(95, 0, 170, 30);
        mainLabel.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:14];
        mainLabel.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
        [cell.contentView addSubview:mainLabel]; 

        UILabel *despLabel=[[UILabel alloc]init];
        despLabel.tag=despTag;
        despLabel.frame=CGRectMake(95, 25, 190, 20);
        despLabel.font= [UIFont systemFontOfSize:12];
        despLabel.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
        [cell.contentView addSubview:despLabel]; 

    } else {

        label = (UILabel *) [cell.contentView viewWithTag:LABEL_TAG];
    }
    switch([indexPath section]){
        case 0:
            { 
            NSString *urlString = [img objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
            urlString=[urlString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@"%20"];

            tname=[mname objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
            tprice=[mprice objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
            tquan=[mquan objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
            tspice=[mspice objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]; 

            UILabel *mainLabel=(UILabel *)[cell.contentView viewWithTag: kMyTag];
            mainLabel.text =  [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",tname];
            UILabel *despLabel=(UILabel *)[cell.contentView viewWithTag: despTag];
            despLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Qty :%@   Spice: %@",tquan,tspice];
            UILabel *subLabel=(UILabel *)[cell.contentView viewWithTag: subTag];
            float pric=[tprice floatValue];
            subLabel.text =  [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Price :%@ %.2f",currencyType, pric];
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Overcomes the issue by removing all the objects from array,then reselects the DB table & reloads uitableview.

Answer (score 0):

it happens because you are not passing any value in `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier`
pass a string value and then use it in `reuseIdentifier` also

Comment: When I passed value to dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier,the cell values gets overwrite.

Comment: try to put switch condition in `if (cell == nil)`

Comment: I put switch condition in if(cell == nil),but the issue of overwriting continues

Comment: ok now you put switch condition in if(cell==nil) then you don't have to use this line

Comment: UILabel *mainLabel=(UILabel *)[cell.contentView viewWithTag: kMyTag];

Comment: set text when you are going to create mainLabel and also put the if(indexPath.section==0) there